Problem with passing indicator to another indicator
In the following code, Why is self.t1 not working?
The output indicates t1 are all Nan except for the last one, while t2 works as expected.
from datetime import datetime
import backtrader as bt
from backtrader.indicators import CrossUp

from feed.md import MarketDataFeed


class Simple(bt.Indicator):
    lines = ('av',)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def next(self):
        self.lines.av[0] = self.data[0]

class TestIndicator(bt.Indicator):
    lines = ("vc1",)

    def __init__(self):
        self.vc1 = self.data.close > self.data.open
        self.c1 = CrossUp(self.vc1, 0.5)
        self.t1 = Simple(self.c1)
        self.c2 = CrossUp(self.vc1, 0.5) + 0
        self.t2 = Simple(self.c2)

        print(type(self.c1), type(self.c2))

    def next(self):
        print(
            self.data.datetime.date(0),
            self.c1[0],
            self.c2[0],
            self.t1[0],
            self.t2[0],
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cerebro = bt.Cerebro(stdstats=True)
    cerebro.addindicator(TestIndicator)

    data = MarketDataFeed(
        symbol="AAPL",
        fromdate=datetime(2020, 2, 1),
        todate=datetime(2021, 5, 31),
    )
    cerebro.adddata(data)
    cerebro.broker.setcash(100000.0)
    cerebro.run()


It seems c1 and c2 are different types but still cannot understand what is going on in the background.
<class 'backtrader.indicators.crossover.CrossUp'> <class 'backtrader.linebuffer.LinesOperation'>

